# Remote desktop connection from Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I know it's possible to remote control my workstations from our Windows 2008 server, but, is it possible to do it without first living the current user out?

For example, today I had to support a user in a different office (within the same LAN/domain) so I logged in remotely and talk to the user on the phone. However, if the user could show me what they were trying to do it would be  million times easier.

Is this functionality possible 'out of the box' with Microsoft Windows Server 2008?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Is this some sort of terminal services, or just standard Windows client?

Comment: Its standard windows xp pro clients.

Comment: Cool, then my answer should be relevant - you were mentioning Windows Server, so I got a bit confused as to whether this was terminal services or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality has been in Windows for ages - it's called Windows Remote Assistance.

It allows you to help someone so you and they can both see and use the computer at the same time. It's ideal when you are trying to get somebody to show you what they are doing, or to show them how to do something.

It also has a mode where you can enter the remote hostname/IP address and it will prompt them to accept or decline your remote assistance invitation.

Comment: Do you know where this would be on Microsoft Server 2008? I only seem to have Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: You can get this from your Windows machine, no need to go to the server to do it.

Comment: I ideally wanted something that requires no intervention on the recipients workstation. A simple may I connect option, maybe. Is that what the assistance tool does?

Comment: Yes, what it does is bring up a message on their screen saying "Ben is offering Remote Assistance - would you like to allow them to help?" with Yes/No buttons.

Answer (score 2):

See [Windows Desktop Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Windows_Desktop_Sharing)

Answer (score 0):

use tightvnc http://www.tightvnc.com/ and you can share the screen.